# How to get logs of Cloud Functions from another cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I am trying to view logs that my cloud functions generate. Looking at the Firebase Documentation, there is a CLI command that we can use to do that, which is:

```
firebase functions:log
```

This command prints out all the logs generated by all the cloud functions. How can I put this command inside of another Cloud function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions uses the [Cloud Logging API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) for its logging, which has a [LoggingService](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rpc/google.logging.v2#google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2) that seems to do what you want.